# update one row of the table by using PDO method

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-update

I'm new beginer in php development and I need your help if it is possible.
I want to update just one row in the table 'vehicule' wihtout changing all rows. Here is my php page modif_vehicule_ctrl.php:

```
try{
    // vérifier si les cases sont remplies ou pas
    if(!isset($_POST['marqueVehicule'])||empty($_POST['marqueVehicule']))throw new Exception("Vous n'avez pas saisi la marque du véhicule");
    else if(!isset($_POST['matriculeVehicule'])||empty($_POST['matriculeVehicule']))throw new Exception("Vous n'avez pas saisi le matricule du véhicule");
    else if(!isset($_POST['placeVehicule'])||empty($_POST['placeVehicule']))throw new Exception("Vous n'avez pas saisi le nombre de places du véhicule");
    else if(!isset($_POST['entretienVehicule'])||empty($_POST['entretienVehicule']))throw new Exception("Vous n'avez pas saisi la date de l'entretien");
    else if(!isset($_POST['parkingVehicule'])||empty($_POST['parkingVehicule']))throw new Exception("Vous n'avez pas saisi la palce du parking");
    else if(!isset($_POST['servicePret'])||empty($_POST['servicePret'])) throw new Exception("Vous n'avez pas saisi le service de prêt");
    else if(!isset($_POST['datePret'])||empty($_POST['datePret'])) throw new Exception("Vous n'avez pas saisi la date de prêt si le véhicule est prêté");

    // chargement bdd
    include('mabase.php');

    // connexion
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host='.$PDO_MYSQL_HOST.';dbname='.$PDO_MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME, $PDO_MYSQL_LOGIN, $PDO_MYSQL_PASSWORD);
    //$id= $_GET['id_vehicule'];
    // preparation de la requeste sql et prevention d'injections 
    $req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE vehicule SET marqueVehicule=?, matriculeVehicule=?, placeVehicule=?, entretienVehicule=?, parkingVehicule=?, servicePret=?, datePret=? WHERE id_vehicule=?');
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: all the table 'vehicule' is updated with this command. I want to update juste one row not all rows

Comment: Either id_vehicule is the same in all rows, which shouldn't be, or you are running some other query. Make sure that id_vehicule contains an **unique** value for each row.

Comment: yes id_vehicule contains an unique value for each row. I don't understand where is the problem exactly

Comment: Check the query you run. Most likely you are running another code where a WHERE condition is not set.